# Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

For example, spy stuff like James Bond, 24, Tom Clancy, have some elements of sci-fi, but are a genre unto themselves. Should we include them in the list of on topic discussions?

Comment: Similar reasonings should apply to other cases such as [Neal Stephenson's baroque cycle](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/506/are-questions-about-neal-stephensons-baroque-cycle-allowed-on-this-site).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I suggest the following guidelines (improvements welcome):

1. If it's marketed as SF, it's on-topic.
2. If magic, futuristic science or technology, alternate history, or other [sf-nal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction) concept is an important part of the overall plot, it's on-topic. (*Alice in Wonderland*, *Clockwork Orange*, etc.)
3. If the question is specifically about an sf-nal element, even if it's only a minor part of the work, it's on-topic.
4. If it's set in an on-topic universe, it's on-topic.
5. If you're not sure it's SF but you think a good case can be made for it, it's on-topic.
6. If there is a minor supernatural element (e.g. a fortune teller's prediction comes true, or someone sees a ghost, or a story for children involving anthropomorphic animals) but it's just a throwaway plot element that's not particularly relevant to the question, it's off-topic.

This is a rather inclusive policy. I think being inclusive will generate less friction (better have a few questions that purists can just snub, than cause bad feelings by closing borderline questions). This isn't to say you shouldn't vote to close if you feel that a borderline question is on the wrong side of the border, but please explain your reasoning when you cast your close vote.

Data point: [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/index.php/ISFDB:Policy#Definitions) excludes “[technothrillers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Techno-thriller)” but includes “non-genre speculative fiction”. It doesn't include any of [Fleming](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?Ian_Fleming)'s Bond novels, but has [Burgess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Burgess)'s full bibliography. I don't claim ISFDB has particularly clear rules; I suspect that because SF.SE is more community-run, we'll end up more inclusive than ISFDB.

Comment: Why is "sf-nal" short for "Speculative Fiction"?

Comment: @OrangeDog To form an adjective from the term "SF", patterned after "science fictional"; I imagine "speculative fictional" (or "speculatively fictional"?) sounded just as odd, and wouldn't have matched the use of "SF" through the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 15):

Should depend on how heavily incorporated the sci-fi elements are in the spy-fi property.

*Moonraker* would lean a lot in the sci-fi elements. Probably.

Whereas another film in the James Bond franchise, e.g. *On Her Majesty's Service*, far less so.

But then we're onto the slippery slope of topics and what is and isn't right for the site.

And it's a totally separate discussion to fantasy, which for a long time is mentioned in the same breath as sci-fi that they're pretty much bookshelf genre neighbours.

Comment: Perhaps it should depend on how heavily incorporated the sci-fi elements are, to the question.

Answer (score 11):

The boundaries of genre are fuzzy, and it would be a shame to exclude a work simply because of what a marketing department calls a work. I'd be fine with these questions where they relate to elements of the story that are explicitly science-fiction or fantasy.

Is "Moonraker" science-fiction? One could argue that, but it's really nothing more than spies and soldiers... IN SPACE! On the other hand, "A Clockwork Orange" is less obviously science-fiction, but it involves societal change.

Let's ask a few of these questions and see how they go.