# Is frontier medicine in House, M.D. on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spy movies/ books: On topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/spy-movies-books-on-topic)

House, M.D. is clearly neither science fiction nor fantasy (even though [this io9 article](http://io9.com/5346227/5-reasons-why-house-md-is-science-fiction) begs to differ), but some individual episodes have science fiction sub-plots.

In one episode, for instance, the team records a patient's brain activity to visual stimuli for several hours in order to reconstruct an image she is seeing in her mind. And occasionally, there are cases of medical [Forgotten Phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForgottenPhlebotinum).

To ask the question more broadly: are science fiction and fantasy sub-plots / story arcs / episodes of non-sf-and-f works on topic? How does one decide?

Comment: Do [the guidelines here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/337/spy-movies-books-on-topic) answer your interrogations?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I apparently missed this on the related list while I was composing the question.

Comment: I've given that question a more general title since it's our reference question on the topic (should have done it sooner).

Comment: Argh, I blame you for the lost hour of my life! *shakes fist* TV Tropes!

Answer (score 2):

Any episode, subplot, story arc, etc that has SciFi connotations, even though the entirety of the series/story may not have, is considered on topic.

[Meta discussion about the scope of the site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/350/1109)