# Are questions about Orphan Black allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

In trying to ask a question about the BBC show [Orphan Black](http://www.bbcamerica.com/orphan-black/), I noticed there is no tag for it. Are questions about the show off-topic, or is it just that none have been asked yet?

Based on the answers to this question so far, I've gone ahead and [posted my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59741/where-does-orphan-black-take-place).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_Black):

> *Orphan Black* is a Canadian science fiction television series […] starring Tatiana Maslany as several identical people who are revealed to be clones.

I haven't watched the show myself, but it sounds like it would be on-topic to me.

We already have a [clones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clones) tag, so clones and clone-related media are certainly on-topic.

Otherwise, if consensus says that it’s off-topic here, then there are [a few questions about *Orphan Black*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orphan-black) on the [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com), so I’m sure a good question could find a home there.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't watched it (yet!  It's on my list, as I've heard it is pretty good), but my understanding is that human cloning is a central plot point throughout the series.

As such, I believe it is firmly considered on-topic here.

If [*Junior* is on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3360/1359), then this certainly should be.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike *everyone else* ( :p ), I have watched the show. It's sci-fi.  The premise is that there were successful human clones made ~20 years ago, and the main character (in the present day) learns she's one of them.

Comment: OMG!  Spoilers!!! :P

Comment: This is all in the premise of the show.  Everything except for the '20 year ago' bit is revealed in the pilot.  It also doesn't take long for them to establish they're not quick-grown clones.

Comment: Yeah... If you've *watched* it :P  I was joking about the spoilers, however ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you see a show that is classified as sci-fi, but there is no tag about it, don't worry.

Ask your question and tag it with something similar while mentioning (on a comment) for a high rep user to create the tag for you.