# Are all questions about games on-topic as long as they contain some SciFi or Fantasy element?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/60257/19561) asks for identification of a game containing fantasy elements (a knight fighting skeletons in a graveyard). It was closed as off-topic, then reopened since games *in general* aren't off-topic.

The consensus in [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3356/19561) was that questions about works just containing fantasy elements aren't necessarily on-topic just because of the fantasy elements.

This question sounds as if it would be more at home at Arqade, except for the fact that [identification questions are off-topic there](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4168/75191), even though they [still have the tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info).

So before we go through another close/reopen cycle, let's discuss here if it's on-topic or not. Is it?

Comment: *All* questions about games: clearly "No".  *Some* questions about games: "Yes".

Comment: I know this is a necro comment, but it has to be said: Just because a question is off-topic on one SE does **not** mean it is on-topic in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple answer for whether a game question is on-topic if it contains some Sci-Fi or Fantasy element.

If the **question** relates to Sci-Fi for Fantasy, it is on-topic.  Period.

This means you can ask Sci-Fi or Fantasy questions about video games, but **not** video game questions about a Sci-Fi or Fantasy video game.

The content of the material is not important - the content of your **question** determines whether it is on-topic, and I think that's satisfactory.  If there is enough Sci-Fi or Fantasy content in your video game to ask a solid Sci-Fi or Fantasy question about it, then the question is on-topic.

[/Simple Answer]

---

Now, Identification Questions are more problematic, but you can still follow this rule when asking an Identification question.

Are the elements you're using to identify the game Sci-Fi or Fantasy related?  Then it's on-topic, but you'd better make sure those elements are specific enough, or it will get downvoted for low-quality details.

This is a Sci-Fi/Fantasy SE, so we expect our questions to be Sci-Fi and Fantasy based.  If they're not, they're off-topic.  If they are, they will be treated as any other Sci-Fi/Fantasy question.

Answer (score 16):

What is a game if not an interactive story? We take questions about the background and story of sci-fi and fantasy games just like we do any other sci-fi or fantasy work. The elements described in the game ID question are clearly on-topic, and we allow identification questions, so I think the question is squarely on-topic.

Comment: Space Invaders, for instance, isn't really an interactive story. It's a game. I don't think a question like "What's the name of that game where you shoot aliens that descend" is a science fiction question.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: How about: "What propulsion system do the ships in Space Invaders use, allowing them to hover over the ground?"

Comment: That would be fine, assuming one could find supporting information about the game's background. It's not about the *game*, it's about the setting, which feels, to me, on topic.

Answer (score 11):

Questions about [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) are explicitly allowed (as long as it's not about the game mechanics), as are [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions.

As far as I'm concerned, combining the two doesn't seem like any sort of a stretch, especially if/when the questions are phrased in a way that actually allows a single acceptable answer.

The usual rules (not too broad, not a "list" question, etc) do obviously still apply.

Answer (score 2):

We discussed this earlier in chat and my contribution and position on the matter is: *I think the issue is the element of the game -- is it truly sci-fi or fantasy? For example, I wouldn't want to see questions about Donkey Kong just because a princess might make an appearance, and the question is about strategy, not the elemental story of the game.*

I don't believe our site is the appropriate one to discuss game strategy; it shouldn't be allowed on a technicality simply because a minute element of sci-fi or fantasy exists within the game's lore. American McGee's *Alice*¹, for example, is obviously based on Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking Glass*, which, yes, is a work of fantasy. I would not be impressed by a question asking about plot points *for the sole purpose of beating the game*.

I could say that I wouldn't then mind lore for the sake of lore questions, but if that were the motivation, it would seem the question would (or ought to) have come directly through SFF.se and not be shifted over from Aquade. I can't help but worry that the underlying theme of gaming questions is going to be strategy, which I think would be inappropriate for our site. I would prefer not to see those questions here. YMMV, of course.

¹<sub>Excellent soundtrack by Chris Vrenna</sub>

Comment: What about story-identification gaming questions?

Comment: [Some DK questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong) for your entertainment, Slythe-**rincess** ;)

Comment: @Keen -- By "lore" I meant story, so my third paragraph is how I feel about story ID. I'm not a fan of it in general. I realize this is an unpopular view.

Comment: @bitmask - Well, thank you! I've beaten the Pie Factory and turned that game over hundreds of times :D Back in the day, back in the day ...

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know ID Requests on Arqade aren't off topic as I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129218/what-game-does-extra-credits-use-in-the-working-conditions-episode-at-612) almost a year ago and it was never closed, the link in the OP's question is dated back to 2 years ago. To my knowledge ID Requests must meet **certain strict criteria** otherwise they're closed, Arqade's I think is a screen shot, Anime and Manga has a [Meta Question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/892/63) on it requiring 2 points or a picture, (my question originally didn't have one but I did link to the video and indicated the time, someone edited the image in for me).

As for if something is on-topic here I'd think of it like this. If the story contains one of these elements as a major/significant plot point it's on topic:

- A time setting in the future, in alternative timelines, or in a historical past that contradicts known facts of history or the archaeological record.
- A spatial setting or scenes in outer space (e.g. spaceflight), on other worlds, or on subterranean earth.
- Characters that include aliens, mutants, androids, or humanoid robots and other types of characters arising from a future human evolution.
- Futuristic or plausible technology such as ray guns, teleportation machines, and humanoid computers.
- Scientific principles that are new or that contradict accepted physical laws, for example time travel, wormholes, or faster-than-light travel or communication.
- New and different political or social systems, e.g. dystopian, post-scarcity, or post-apocalyptic.
- Paranormal abilities such as mind control, telepathy, telekinesis, and teleportation.
- Other universes or dimensions and travel between them.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_fiction#Definition)

I'd also add anything which is seen as Magic as well regardless if it's actually a mystical force (Magecraft, True Magic in the Nasuverse), super advanced technology which is seen as magic by everyone else (Asgard, Goa'uld from Stargate) or a hybrid of the 2 (the Program like Magic Systems in Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha) since it kinda is a merger of the 5th and 7th points

But then you have to ask yourself, where can I get a better answer? Practically almost every Anime/Manga/Light Novel/Visual Novel is sci fi whether it's using magical powers like in [dragonball](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball) or weather it's just science like in Robotech, even Arqade accepts story-line questions like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81674/why-was-caius-supposed-to-be-immortal). In this case I'd do a search for existing tags on here, Arqade and [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), see how many questions have been asked/answers and how detailed they are, which ever site has answers more to your liking is probably your best bet.

However it's a good idea to think about what you're trying to get out of the question ie. I asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47968/which-entity-of-the-cthulhu-mythos-does-mary-meet) here over Anime and Manga because I was after an ID of a Cthulhu Mythos creature, I knew from the references I give that Mary met something from the Cthulhu Mythos and figured I'd more likely get an answer here considering the number of questions on the Cthulhu Mythos and Lovecraft.

```
                                              {Question about Anime}
                             TV and Movies -----------Ask On------------
                                /\   ||                                ||
               Ask On           ||   ||           Ask On               ||
   {Question about TV or Movie} ||   || {Question about Sci Fi Story}  ||
                                ||   ||                                ||
         {Question about Story} ||   \/    {Question about Anime}      \/
 Aquade --------Ask On---------> Sci Fi --------Ask On---------> Anime and Manga
   ||                                                                  /\
   ||                                                                  ||
   --------------------------------Ask On-------------------------------
                        {Question about JRPG Story}
```

^ above is what I'd like to think how ideally questions get put on a site when one thinks about where to ask, ofcause we still get [Duplicate Cross-Site Questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173713/when-exactly-did-everyone-figure-out-about-lucy#comment236017_173713) so it doesn't work all that well.

Comment: Read [Arqade's current Tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).  Game identification is off topic there.

Comment: Also 'waiting a few months' to get a post migrated ensures it can't be migrated, as we can't migrate questions older than [60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/158781).

Comment: @Keen (Comment 1) Bad Wording that is, they are Off Topic unless they have some sort of artifact, in most cases a screen shot, which kinda seems like a double standard however after i asked about it on the [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/9751/30879) the help center pages related to it might end up being changed to indicate this

Comment: @Keen (Comment 2) i didn't know about the 60 days thing, i've removed that from my post and edited my diagram, migration was just a fall back, in all cases one should think very carefully where they can get the best answer, though it's problematic when Sci Fi, Anime and Manga and TV and Movies are interchangeable since Gundam story related questions technically could go in all 3 are be on topic

Answer (score -2):

> This question sounds as if it would be more at home at Arqade,[...]

**Questions may be on-topic at more than one site at the same time.**  Whether a question is on-topic somewhere else has nothing whatsoever to do with whether it is on-topic here.  The only reason we should even care about other sites' scopes is when we're trying to decide between migration and regular closure for a question which is undoubtedly off-topic here.

Now, let's look at the actual question in this case:

> Trying to find a game I played as a kid, most likely on a PS2 (99% sure).
>
> It's an old game where, I believe, you play as a knight, and during the first few levels it is night time and you fight skeletons in a cemetery. Not much to go off of but thanks for whatever help.
>
> EDIT: I really want to say it was made by Capcom, but I can't be sure. It was also not a sidescroller, it was a full 3D action/adventure.

While fighting skeletons in a cemetery would probably be a moderately unusual plot for most SFnal stories, it's [a fairly common plot](https://www.google.com/search?q=video+game+fight+skeletons+cemetery) for video games of the generation OP is describing (Don't believe me? The accepted answer lists no less than *four* possibilities, not counting one which the OP rejected.).  The other details are helpful, true, but not really sufficient.  By the time the PS2 was widely available, 3D games had already captured a large segment of the market.  [Action-adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-adventure_game) scarcely means anything, unless you happen to be talking about one of the *Zelda* games.  And Capcom made [a lot of games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Capcom_games:_0%E2%80%93D).

Frankly, **I would close-vote this question as too broad**, if it didn't already have an accepted answer (which rather defeats the point of the exercise).  It's really lean on detail and people seem to have come up with an answer by guessing rather than via the details in the question.

(Contrary to claims in the comments, [we do close story ID questions with insufficient detail](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano).)

Comment: We don't close ID questions on this site for being low on details.

Comment: @KutuluMike: Never heard that one before.  Source?

Comment: Source: every ID question on this site.

Comment: @KutuluMike: You mean like [all of these](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano)?

Comment: @Kevin - Most of those questions are awful and unanswerable by any reasonable means

Comment: @Valorum: So was this question.

Comment: Clearly it wasn't. It has two answers correctly identifying it.

Comment: @Kevin you've found 127 out of EIGHT THOUSAND. 1.5% doesn't seem like something that happens very often

Comment: @phantom42: Getting lucky after 4+ guesses is not "reasonable."

Comment: Actually, if you look at the timestamps, Dedpool got it right on his first try first. Valorum came in afterwards and incorporated it into his own answer.

Comment: @Kevin- In fairness, I was being a touch lazy. There's only a very small number of games that fit the bill and rather than finding those where you fight skeletons in a graveyard, I just slung all the ones where you fight medieval skeletons