# Is The 39 Clues on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about [The 39 Clues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_39_Clues) book series on-topic here? They are arguably science fiction, as one central theme is a DNA-altering serum giving people amazing powers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The series itself, from a cursory glance at [the Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_39_Clues), appears to be a light-sci-fi light-fantasy series, so I think questions about the series itself are on-topic here.

However, I caution you that the questions you ask must pertain to the story itself, or to elements of the story that are sci-fi or fantasy related.

We've had a few questions lately asking about real-world materials in sci-fi shows, and the conclusion we've reached is that just because something happens *in* a sci-fi or fantasy series does not make it sci-fi or fantasy.  [This question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4776/20533) and the answers to it are a good primer for that.

However, the best way to find out if your question is valid is to simply ask away!  Well-formatted questions are always welcome, and if they are off-topic, the worst that can happen is that we'll politely inform you of it and close the question.  So it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: I've posted a [question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68692/32466) based on your advice. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: @Scimonster - Your question seems well on topic.

Answer (score 8):

> one central theme is a DNA-altering serum giving people amazing powers.

Generally speaking, the books sound to be on-topic. I would caution, however, that based on looking over [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_39_Clues), it sounds as though much of the books themselves may fall outside the scope. Questions not specifically about a SF/F related element of the book may be deemed off-topic.

Comment: So what would a question like "Why did person X do Y in location Z?" be on- or off-topic? Y being something about the story, and not 100% sci-fi.

Comment: IMO, it would be on-topic, but there have been a few questions lately which were closed for not being strictly SF/F related. I'll try to dig up some examples if I have some time today.

Comment: @scimonster I'd say at a glance no that's off-topic... But it's hard to say that without seeing the question,  do you have a question in mind?

Comment: @Pureferret The user has posted this question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68692/did-fiske-cahill-try-to-stop-the-holts-from-blowing-up-the-franklin-institute so take it as you will.