# Are Toy Story questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've noticed there are a few *Toy Story* questions on the site. There are also the [Toy Story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toy-story-2+toy-story) and [Toy Story 2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toy-story-2) tags.

Should they be closed for being off-topic? I fail to see how *Toy Story* is sci-fi or fantasy as neither magic nor other fantastical elements are used to bring the toys to life.

According to [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/4678) simply having talking animals does not make it fantasy, I would argue the same is true for talking toys.

Comment: ... it has sentient toys in the same world as human beings. how is that not fantasy?

Comment: Note that acceptance isn't a good way to define consensus on Meta; Zibbobz's (accepted) answer has five upvotes and 3 downvotes, while Richard's answer has 14 upvotes and no downvotes; that's a much better measure of consensis

Answer (score 11):

*Toy Story* is fantasy because the characters (toys) in the show act as sentient, which is decidedly *not* reality. So, no, these questions should not be closed as they are on-topic.

In reference to your edit, *Toy Story* does cover a key point in the [answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/4678) you referenced:

> Their speaking was somehow fantastical to the other characters.
>
> The talking rats in Ratatouille would certainly fall into the latter category. There's no specific evidence of how they became intelligent but it's clear from the scenes in the film that animal sentience certainly isn't a normal feature of that universe.

Given that they go to lengths to hide their sentience from humans, I would argue that their speaking would be fantastical to the other (human) characters.

**Regardless, such a question about Toy Story should deal with the fantastical elements of the story to be on-topic.**

Comment: +1 | No need for me to add anything to this perfect answer. Toy Story and Ratatouille are both fantastic realms with sentience being part of a creature/entity (toy) we would normally not consider sentient.