# Is Charlotte's Web on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I never really thought of *Charlotte's Web* by E.B. White as fantasy (and definitely not science fiction), but it's definitely not realistic; now that I am thinking about it, I realize that it has many talking, intelligent animals, and is probably as close to fantasy as it is to any other genre.  Also, I have a question I am dying to ask about it, and this site is the only one with a possibility of the question being on-topic.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5119/31394). Basically, if talking animals are par for the course in-universe (e.g. Farthing Wood), it's not fantasy; but if they're uplifted or supernatural, then it is. I'd say *Charlotte's Web* is **just on the boundary**, since all the animals can talk to each other, but Fern is the only human who can hear/understand them.

Comment: @randal'thor Sigh.  So can I ask my question?

Comment: id let charlottes web fly... as ontopic.

Comment: @CHEESE What *is* your question, specifically? Whether it's about specifically fantasy-ish elements could make a difference.

Comment: @randal'thor It is not at all about fantasy; it is about whether the goose spells terrific TEERRRRIIFFIICCCCCC or TEERRRRIIFFIICCCCCCCCCC.

Comment: @CHEESE My guess would be off-topic (I'll write up an answer later if nobody else does). You might *possibly* be able to get away with asking on [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com), if it's about a certain "idio-idio-idiosyncratic" way of speaking English, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @randal'thor I tried them before I tried us, and it apparently will not work.

Comment: @rand: Is *A Christmas Carol* (by Charles Dickens) on topic?  Just because of the ghosts?  That would be silly; except for the brief appearance of Marley’s ghost, they’re just a dream.  …  Are the Muppets on topic?  All the animals talk (except for the chickens; Henson’s version of [Pluto](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17355/30482 "What is the difference between Goofy and Pluto?")); so, based on the discussion here, they aren’t (in general; [Why do the Twin Towers still stand in the Kermit-less world?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121617/30482) is about alternative history).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So why, when I flagged [Why didn’t Tiny Tim die?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111671/30482) as off-topic, was my flag declined?  The question even says, “The same question applies to the non-Muppet version(s).” (although that remark was added (by the OP) after my flag was raised and declined).  And it isn’t even about a fantastical element of the story; it’s about the relationship between wealth and health.  …  P.S. Does SF&F really need a [muppet-christmas-carol] tag?

Comment: @PeregrineRook There are always going to be grey areas in what counts as SF/F or not; it's hard to define and can often be argued ad nauseam. *Alice in Wonderland* is "just a dream", but many would still say it's definitely on-topic. As for why your flag was declined, ask [the people who declined it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/70905), not me :-) Also, this looks like it could become a long and interesting discussion (and has become less relevant to CHEESE's question) - shall we take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley)?

Comment: @CHEESE Maybe you ask on Movies & TV? might be able to get an answer based on a film version...

Comment: I would be a lot more interested in defended this as being on-topic if it wasn't going to result in a ridiculous question about spelling.

Comment: @DCShannon I completely agree, because it's a fantastical scenario in a mundane world. I'd still classify that as fantasy (Not all fantasy has magic, and dragons, and the supernatural OH MY!).

Answer (score 7):

### No.

The [highest-voted answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/31394) to [Are anthropomorphic animals by themselves enough to deem a work fantasy?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy) tells us that:

> Anthropomorphic/Sentient/Talking animals don't, in and of themselves, make a film/book/TV programme/comic into a fantasy if the [central conceit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_conceit) is that talking animals do *already* exist within that fictional universe.
>
> **That said, we would consider talking animals to be part of a fantasy if:**
>
> - They had been **[uplifted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_(science_fiction))** in some way (either by technology or magic)
> - Their speaking was **somehow fantastical** to the other characters.

Neither of these is the case in *Charlotte's Web*. All the animals are able to talk to each other as a matter of course, and there's nothing fantastical about this. None of the humans except Fern can understand them, but the in-universe explanation for this is that Fern is younger and more sympathetic and listens to them better. The only animal who shows abilities beyond that of a normal animal is Charlotte, and she's just unusually intelligent rather than being "uplifted" by some technology or magic (or being bitten by a radioactive human).

Comment: +1 for "being bitten by a radioactive human" :-)