# Is "The Rats of NIMH" series on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm aware anthromorphic animals are rarely on topic. But what about the rats of NIMH series? Over [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy/5119#5119) Kevin answers

> Our final criterion, then, is this:
>
> If the animal's non-human nature has substantial narrative focus, then the story is probably on-topic. Stories that pass this criterion tend to ask and answer questions such as the following (not an exhaustive list):
>
> What would it be like to be an intelligent [animal]?
> How would a mixed society of humans and [animal]s work?
> How would a mixed society of [animal]s and [other animal]s work?
> What would an intelligent [animal] think of humans?
> What would a human think of an intelligent [animal]?
> Why are these [animal]s intelligent, anyway?

According to this the NIMH series is most certainly on topic, though displaying no other fantastical elements.

Is this universally agreed?

Comment: You might wish to note that Kevin's answer (although in broad agreement with mine) isn't the accepted consensus answer. [This is](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/20774).

Comment: Please realise the "accepted answer" is meaningless on meta, it's the votes that count.

Comment: Strange: I was sure this had been asked before on SFF meta, but apparently not.

Comment: @Valorum Duh. Thats why I asked it.

Comment: @TheAsh - Your wording confused me. Is it universally agreed? No, it's not the highest voted answer.

Comment: @Valorum perhaps your answer was merely written better.  Or perhaps the answers are complementary. Thats why I asked for clarification

Comment: @Edlothiad, others: **Please don't use my +4 answer** in place of Valorum's +19.  It's obvious which way the votes have gone and I did not win.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The usual test is to look at conceit and marketing. **Both of those heavily indicate that this book series is (science) fantasy, and hence on-topic**

---

### Central Conceit.

A group of rats has been subjected to bio-medical experimentation and has become intellectually "uplifted" to human levels of intelligence. They then develop a civilisation. Humans interacting with these rats are the central plot of the book.

> Mrs. Frisby discovers the rats have a literate and mechanized society.
>   They have technology such as elevators, have tapped the electricity
>   grid to provide lighting and heating, and have acquired other human
>   skills, such as storing food for the winter. Their leader, Nicodemus,
>   tells Mrs. Frisby of the rats' capture by scientists working for a
>   laboratory located at the [National Institute of Mental Health](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs._Frisby_and_the_Rats_of_NIMH) (NIMH)
>   and the subsequent experiments that the humans performed on the rats,
>   which increased the rats' intelligence to the point of being able to
>   read, write, and operate complicated machines, as well as enhancing
>   their longevity and strength.

Our existing [policy on talking animals](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy?noredirect=1&lq=1) is that they don't count unless...

> *They had been uplifted in some way (either by technology or magic)*

### Marketing

Both the book series and the subsequent film were heavily marketed as children's fantasy.

> "...thought-provoking fantasy"

[image]

> "Right before your eyes and beyond your wildest dream"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## I'd say yes.

Some of the major things in these stories is that the rats became intelligent through a laboratory experiment, became intelligent enough to escape, escaped, *created their own society*... And don't forget that they can communicate with humans, and do things like farm carrots.

It's definitely SFF. I'd say it's unquestionably on topic.