# Is "V for Vendetta" film on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm specifically asking about the film, not the comics.

Comment: Why should it be, why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @SQB - Don't know enough either way, but it wasn't marketed as SciFi.

Comment: What is the context of the question?   I wonder if it would make a difference if you were asking a question specifically about the sci-fi aspects of the comics or not.

Comment: @Zoredache - I specifically narrowed it down to the film, not the comics

Comment: Right but I am thinking it may matter if you were asking about the science/technology versus asking about the politics or something else.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, absolutely. The film is set in 2038 in a post-apocalyptic future. The titular character's origin story suggests that he has been the victim of genetic experimentation and the (albeit largely unseen) "fate" computer is clearly a work of immense technical sophistication.

Any one of these features would be sufficient to render it on-topic.

Comment: Taking place in the future or being post-apocalyptic doesn't make it on-topic.

Comment: @Kevin - I don't recall any discussion on that topic. Posted: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5351/does-a-work-being-set-in-post-apocalyptic-future-automatically-make-it-in-scope

Comment: @DVK It was broached briefly, but not in the context of whether post-apocalyptic scenarios are off-topic: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/122/3567

Comment: In addition, the main character is enhanced via genetic experimentation and possibly technology - he definitely falls somewhat into the "superhuman" category.

Answer (score 2):

I've never watched the movie or read the comics, but I don't see anything on IMDB or Wikipedia that suggests the movie as a whole would be on-topic, so I'd say no (unless it's specifically about a piece of future technology that happens to be in the movie). Any fictional technology is just movie flashiness and not enough to make it sci-fi.

Our current guidelines:

> 1. If it's marketed as SF, it's on-topic.

IMDB says "Action | Drama | Thriller," Wikipedia says "Political Thriller." Nope

> 2. If magic, futuristic science or technology, alternate history, or other [sf-nal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction) concept is an important part of the overall plot, it's on-topic. (*Alice in Wonderland*, *Clockwork Orange*, etc.)

If the plot summary doesn't mention any future tech, it's clearly not integral to the plot.

> 3. If the question is specifically about an sf-nal element, even if it's only a minor part of the work, it's on-topic.

As I said, if the question is about a specific scifi piece of the movie, OK.

> 4. If it's set in an on-topic universe, it's on-topic.

Nope

> 5. If you're not sure it's SF but you think a good case can be made for it, it's on-topic.

I don't see anyone making a good case for it.

> 6. If there is a minor supernatural element (e.g. a fortune teller's prediction comes true, or someone sees a ghost, or a story for children involving anthropomorphic animals) but it's just a throwaway plot element that's not particularly relevant to the question, it's off-topic.

https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/344/3267

Comment: re: Point #5. Was my case (above) not good enough for you? * sniff *

Comment: @Richard No, it wasn't. Setting alone doesn't make a movie scifi. If I added the words "Computer, end program" to the end of *To Kill a Mockingbird*, would that make absolutely any question on the book on-topic here? That would be absurd.

Comment: If a movie is really scifi, the setting will be integrated enough with the plot that it's not a "throwaway plot element."