# Should I vote to close based on my opinion or community consensus?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

A question has recently been asked about 'A Series of Unfortunate Events' which has attracted a number of close votes (as off-topic).

Rand al'Thor  points out that the current consensus on Lemony Snicket is that it's on-topic (see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8008/are-questions-about-lemony-snickets-a-series-of-unfortunate-events-considered/8073#8073)).

I happen to disagree with this decision. **Should I vote to close based on my personal opinion, or the general consensus of the community?**

Comment: I believe this sort of question has already been asked.

Comment: @Adamant Great minds think alike.

Comment: You're abusing your ability to VTC to try to re-prosecute a case that's already been lost

Comment: So you guys have answered my question as well by closing this as a duplicate.  You're saying that I should VTC based on consensus, not my opinion.  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a dupe, but by making it about one tag, you've convinced people that it's a dupe. I've edited to make it slightly more generic and used my de-dupe hammer to reopen it.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest NOT voting contrary to known-to-you community consensus, even if it is technically legal to do so.

Why?

Because the end result will be the same (even if you find 5 more people who agree with you that community consensus is wrong and VTC, the question WILL get reopened, either by 5 more people who agree with community consensus, or by a moderator - because typically moderator votes follow community consensus as defined by Meta).

But you will, in the process:

- Create extra work for people (VTRO voters OR moderators)
- Potentially create bad feelings for the OP ("why are people voting against the rules? Must be a personal attack")
- Potentially create bad feelings for the community (while it is technically your right to VTC against community consensus, it does feel a bit like a mean-spirited challenge to the community, from a certain point of view - even if you didn't *mean* it that way)

Comment: +1. See also [my explanation](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5479/5373) on another meta of how **downvotes reflect personal opinion** whereas **close votes reflect community consensus** (or at least, that's the way it *should* be).