# Is Field of Dreams on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

The 1989 movie [Field of Dreams](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097351/) starring Kevin Costner is billed as a Fantasy/Drama movie on IMDb as well as Wikipedia.

The movie features the following Fantasy elements (to name a few):

- "Ghosts" of dead baseball players are seen by only certain people.
- The phenomenon of dead baseball players only occur on the baseball field.  the players cannot leave the field for fear of never returning.
- Certain characters seem to share the exact same "vision" regarding what their purpose is and how it is tied to said baseball field.

Would this movie be deemed on-topic for this site?

Comment: My apologies in advance to CreationEdge for this post :P

Comment: Hey, welcome to SFF meta! :-)

Comment: Huh.  Well... it's not really a modern ghost story... but it's not really a modern fantasy either.... I think "open portal to the land of the dead" is close enough to fantasy magic to put it there... but it's definitely an edge example.

Comment: Note that IMDB and Wikipedia are both fan-edited. The keywords chosen (Fantasy/Drama) are not necessarily indicative of what the studio intended.

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e ?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Haven't the guidelines changed a bit since 2011?  I don't really know, I just see talk about it all of the time.

Comment: @Valorum [Oi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E83ZLtYar7s), watch it, spaceman!

Comment: @steelershark Valorum's answer is mostly based off of that post, right? I don't think it's that heavily changed.

Comment: I've been to the Field of Dreams, and it's really more of a Field of Dullness in the Middle of a Cornfield That Looks Like Every Other Cornfield in Iowa

Comment: because its you, ontopic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Tentatively yes, but with a proviso (see below)

### Main Conceit

The ghost story around which the film is based (farmer hears voices, sees ghosts) is on-topic for the site. Aside from the title character, other people such as his daughter and a local author also [see the ghosts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSNyiSetZ8Y&feature=youtu.be&t=30s) as well as elements of his fantastical "*field of dreams*".

On the strength of that, we're led to believe that **the ghosts were real, rather than purely imaginary.**

### Marketing

The film has been marketed as a "magical experience" and a "[glowing tribute to all those who dare to dream](http://digital.sabanciuniv.edu/posters/0081.jpg)" but there's no specific indication that the film was intended to be a straight-up fantasy ghost flick. The ghosts are there to further an allegorical tale about believing in oneself, in the face of opposition.

### Proviso

We already have an established system for dealing with films that have SFF content, but aren't *in themselves* fully on-topic

[Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e)

**Because the film is an "edge-case", it's acceptable to ask questions about those elements that are definitely (or at least arguably) on-topic or that relate to on-topic elements**

---

*"Why did the ghosts pick Kevin Costner's field?"* = Fine
*"What kind of corn does Kevin Costner's character grow"* = Not fine.

Comment: If we asked "What kind of potato does Mark Watney grow" that's on-topic, so why not Costner's corn?

Comment: @CreationEdge There's nothing wrong with that question. See [How should we handle questions that are about non-SF/F elements in a SF/F work?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6594/5184)

Comment: @creationedge - I'd hazard that it's because Watney's setting (in the future / on Mars) is sufficiently scifi that pretty much anything you ask will connect in some substantial way to a scifi concept. Whereas Costner's corn only connects tangentially.

Comment: That sucks... I was really interested in the corn.

Comment: I was only joking. I don't really care about corn.

Comment: @Daft You should. Corn's kind of a big deal.

Comment: @DCShannon - Yes. It's a-maize-ing.