# Would the 1988 comedy "Young Einstein" be on-topic for the site?

Tags: discussion

The 1988 comedy "[**Young Einstein**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Einstein)" is a whimsical take on Albert Einstein. Much about the scientist is changed up and the film has a very slight steam-punk aspect to it both period-wise (early 1900s) and technology-wise. For example, not only does he split an atom using a chisel(!), but he also wires up several items - including a violin - to electricity. It's also anachronistic, with Einstein using the electric violin/guitar to "invent" rock-and-roll, as well as other references to future advances. For the most part, however, it's just a whacky comedy based around a character named Albert Einstein who comes up with the Theory of Relativity after splitting the beer atom.

Anyway, **would this be on-topic here due to the aforementioned reasons, or would it be better to post on Movies SE?**

Comment: I refer the honorable OP to the [answer I gave some time ago](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11979/36526).