# Does Spaced count as sci-fi/fantasy?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about the series Spaced and I am fairly certain that the show's bizarre aesthetic and pseudo-surreal elements qualify it as some form of sci-fi or fantasy, but I may very well have tunnel vision on this one.  So I come here to ask you, the humble inhabitants of the meta board.  Is Spaced sci-fi/fantasy, or is it just weird?

An example of some of the show's weirdness that I believe qualifies the show for being sci-fi/fantasy is season 1 episode 5.  By the end of an episode, a freelance vivisectionist is mauled by a dog (that may or may not be a ghost) that was specifically trained to sniff out and attack the wealthy.

Comment: It might be beneficial to include a link or two and a description of the moments that _do_ count as SFF in your opinion (since the series seems to be somewhat obscure). From a glance, it looks like it's similar to _Scott Pilgrim_ franchise, which is on-topic.

Comment: IMDb list it as Action and Comedy, so I will say it's better suited on [Movies & TV Stack exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review)

Comment: Wait, which Spaced? https://qntm.org/spaced definitely is sci-fi, but you mention "show" and a freelance vivisectionist is mauled by a dog" so that probably isn't it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a *series*, the answer is a very firm no. The fantasy elements are largely similar to those seen in [Ally McBeal](https://youtu.be/Rx88NMh-YRs?t=22s), [Scrubs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9emgC7iuxQ) or [Northern Exposure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoZHUDZN-pI) (a show which the [writers acknowledge](https://web.archive.org/web/20080505031406/http://www.spaced-out.org.uk/about-spaced/whatisspaced.shtml) as being a key influence on the style of their programme).

These sequences are not intended to not be taken literally, are part of a milieu of *'general wackiness'* and aren't part of the core events of the show. In the case of Spaced they may also be drug-induced fantasies.

---

That being said, we have a long-established policy of accepting questions that are about scifi *events* that may occur within non-topical properties.

- [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e)

Point #4 seems the most relevant;

> If the question is specifically about an sf-nal element, even if it's
>   only a minor part of the work, it's on-topic.