# Is Monty Python's Flying Circus on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is the work of Monty Python, as a rule, on topic here?  The world, as depicted in *Monty Python's Flying Circus* is different from the real world in many ways.  One can suffer a dangerous fall while climbing the North Face of the [Uxbridge Road](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaoYSiNDnI0).  The [British Dental Association](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMHHWfSe4TE) is one of the world's premier spy agencies.  And [Mister Neutron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ph-1rzqZCHY) is so powerful, he could destroy the whole world.

Of course, the show has no continuity, but clearly anthology shows like *The Twilight Zone* are on topic.  The one episode of the *Circus* that  has a single running plot is the Mister Neutron episode, which is certainly SF (as well as possibly the worst episode in the show's whole run).  There are also other sketches with clear fantasy or SF character.

Personally, I would be inclined to think that only stories/sketches with meaningful fantasy or SF content really should be on topic.  That means the entirety of *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*, probably [The Bishop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDnE-5lD7w8) sketch, but not the Cheese Shop Sketch.  But what do other people think?

Comment: Having seen the entirety of TFC and MP&THG nothing really captured my mind as particularly SFF-nal, while it was a while ago, I’d be inclined to say: *Generally no, unless asking **specifically** about an SFF-nal sketch or scene*.

Comment: @Edlothiad I can't see a colorable argument that Monty Python and the Holy Grail is not a fantasy movie.  'Tis a very silly fantasy movie, but it has a plot with a three-headed ogre, a magic chasm, a sorcerer shooting fire, etc.

Comment: Guess it was a while-er ago than I thought. But the point still stands. THG would just be a longer skit than most.

Comment: @Edlothiad I think we're in basic agreement then.

Answer (score 10):

### No (but see below)

**Questions about the show and sketch-films would generally be off-topic.**

In the main, the show (and the [various sketch-based films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python_filmography)) has little discernible fantasy or science-fiction content, focusing largely on situational comedy, surrealism and parody.

In keeping with [our policy on SFnal elements in non-SFF shows](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e), questions about a small number of *specific* sketches  that contain fantasy (such as the "[Killer Joke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdWGlJrG6sQ)" or "[Bicyle Repair Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=142&v=5Lwjv_VRM7A)") would be on-topic.

### Monty Python and the Holy Grail = Yes

The film [Monty Python and the Holy Grail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python_and_the_Holy_Grail) is an entirely different beast. This movie has a plot-based narrative with overt references to magic, anachronistic technology (including a holy hand-grenade) fantastic beasts and monsters and a largely fantastical setting.

**Questions about this film would generally be on-topic.**

Comment: and I mean King Arthur mythos is basically a trope for the fantasy genre. King with a magic sword, powerful wizard, quest for powerful artifact.... etc etc....  or as [Black Sabbath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YF3jeAPGhrY) would put it *"Circles and Rings, Dragons and kings, weaving a charm and a spell"*

Comment: And who can forget the scene from _Life of Brian_ where [Brian is picked up by an alien spaceship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSY4fEEg4j0).

Comment: And the Life of Brian? I mean as an alternative history, not the obviously Sci-Fi alient space ship 'bit', as @MrLister points out?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Sfnal content is on topic. Parody isn't