# How much dystopia is needed to be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

I have an idea for an ID question, but I'm not sure it's on-topic. I think it's set in the near future, in kind of a dystopian-esque country, but pretty much everything else was normal, and the environment wasn't the focus of the movie. Normally I'd not worry about it and go to M&TV, but they've [stopped doing this sorta thing](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/50636).

**So is simply being set in a dystopia enough to make a question on-topic? If not, how much more SF&F is needed to make it so?**

Comment: If I didn't have my gold badge, I'd vote to close this question as a dupe of [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e).

Comment: @Valorum I don't know if it's a dupe. The examples in that question heavily use SF&F **items**, whereas here I'm asking if only the **setting** is enough to qualify.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Sure. That should be fine.

Comment: After reading through the the question referenced by @Valorum, I think it's pretty clear that the heavily up-voted and accepted answer does cover this case, and that the question would be on-topic. As a result, I've voted to close as a dup.