# Is my story identification question on-topic considering the plot?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

I have been trying to identify a movie that my dad told me about once. Unfortunately since the movies SE doesn't accept story id questions anymore, I want to know if I can ask my question here. The problem is that it doesn't seem like a sci fi movie at first glance.

The plot of the movie is like this:

> The United States and some nondescript Asian country are at war. Both countries decide to determine the outcome of the war by sending their top soldiers to an island in the middle of the ocean to fight each other to the death. The victor of this fight wins the war for their respective nation. However both countries secretly send an assassin to make sure they win. The soldiers find out about the assassin and kill their own country's assassin because they want to make it a fair fight (the American soldier kills the American assassin and the Asian soldier kills the Asian assassin.

The reason I don't think it is a sci fi movie is that it doesn't take place in the future, I think it actually takes place in the year the movie was made (60s - 70s probably). However, the idea that two countries will decide their war by a fight to the death between their top soldiers seems absurd, which makes me think it has elements of a sci-fi story. Sci-fi movies try to answer the question of "what if?", even answers to hypothetical questions about situations which could never happen.

Comment: FWIW I think this was a made-for-tv movie in case anyone can help me identify it.

Comment: On base value it certainly doesn't seem like it would be on topic.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Dystopias are on-topic

Comment: For what it's worth, I just stumbled on a movie called _The 10th Victim_ on Wikipedia's list of dystopian films, and it's summarised as: "In the near-future, wars are avoided by giving people a chance to kill in the ¨Big Hunt¨; the most popular form of entertainment". Somehow, it reminded me of this meta post.

Comment: @Clockwork interesting. By the way I did manage to find the movie on IMDB in case you or anyone else is interested: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065534/. Still not sure if it's on-topic since it doesn't seem dystopian from the summary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### I'd say that this question is on-topic for SFF:SE.

Based on the description (soldiers don't usually get selected to fight '*Battle Royale*' style for their countries against other countries on a kill-or-be-killed island) this sounds like **a dystopia**, something we've decided is [generally on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e).

Depending on the *answer*, further questions may prove to be on- or off-topic.

Comment: How is fewer people dying in war a dystopia?

Comment: @jwodder - Your sensible, well-thought-out questions aren't welcome here :-)

Comment: I'm serious.  You say the work sounds like a dystopia, but I see absolutely nothing dystopic about it.

Comment: Gladiatorial combat certainly isn't normal in modern Western societies, especially when that *Trial of Champions* decides the fate of nations (q.v. Robot Jox). That sounds like quite an unpleasant society to me.

Comment: Unless there are spectators, it's not gladiatorial, and the fates of nations are already decided in the real world by *thousands* of people killing each other.

Comment: @jwodder - It's pretty rare for countries to face an existential threat from troop invasion

Comment: Unfortunately I did find the movie once before and I don't think it was dystopian. It was like Japan and US during WWII. It just happened that they decided to determine the outcome of the war that way for some reason.

Comment: @KodosJohnson - Why would either country (especially the US) agree to that?

Comment: no idea unfortunately. Maybe I'm wrong. I would have to see the movie.

Comment: @jwodder So what? Why would eutopia be any less on topic than dystopia?

Comment: @user14111 TIL that there's a word "eutopia" which is slightly different from "utopia".

Comment: @user14111: I don't believe the movie is either utopian *or* dystopian.  It doesn't sound any more sci-fi than the average action movie.